# Why is Codecademy giving me an unexpected EOF error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

I am new to programming and I am trying to learn to code using Codecademy. While I was trying to do an optional review exercise I encountered an unexpected EOF error while trying to incorporate the input() function in a variable.

I tried the following code. The EOF error appears on line 6:

```
    print("I have information for the following planets:\n")

    print("   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter")
    print("   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune\n")

    weight = input("Please enter Earth weight: ")

    planet = input("Please enter planet number: ")

    # Write an if statement below:
    if planet == 1:
      weight = weight * 0.91
      print("Your weight on Venus will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    elif planet == 2:
      weight = weight * 0.38
      print("Your weight on Mars will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    elif planet == 3:
      weight = weight * 2.34
      print("Your weight on Jupiter will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    elif planet == 4:
      weight = weight * 1.06
      print("Your weight on Saturn will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    elif planet == 5:
      weight = weight * 0.92
      print("Your weight on Uranus will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    elif planet == 6:
      weight = weight * 1.19
      print("Your weight on Neptune will be " + str(weight) + " lb.")
    else:
      print("Unknown planet")
```

This code gives the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "space.py", line 6, in 
weight = input("Please enter Earth weight: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

I expected to be able to give input in the terminal for the variable weight. Instead I got an error. Can someone please explain what I can do to fix my code?

Comment: EXACTLY how did you run this?  If you run it at a terminal, you would not get an EOF error, but you would get a type error because `weight` and `planet` are both strings, not integers.  When I fix that, your code runs for me.

Comment: Can we see the error?

Comment: `EOFError` is raised by `input` when there is no input to read. (Compare to the `readline` method, which returns an empty string when there is no input to read. Since `input` strips the trailing newline from any line read, the exception is needed to distinguish between no input and an empty line like `'\n'`.)

Comment: @TimRoberts As long as `planet` is a string, none of the comparisons will be true, which means none of the `str`/`float` multiplications will be attempted.

Comment: It sounds like Codecademy runs in an online cloud environment that does not have access to your local keyboard input.

Comment: Try running your code somewhere other than the Codecademy environment. You might find it easier to figure out why you're getting runtime exceptions

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon I think that answers my question!